# Error Inflating Class on one activity

Tags: android

I have one activity that my application crashes. I do not understand why it is just this one. I am wondering if it is just a typo somewhere.

Here is the error:

```
09-15 15:30:52.541  16828-16828/dyson.cornell.edu.womeninleadership E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dyson.cornell.edu.womeninleadership/dyson.cornell.edu.womeninleadership.SpeakerElement}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4962)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1914)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
        at dyson.cornell.edu.womeninleadership.SpeakerElement.onCreate(SpeakerElement.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5160)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4962)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1914)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at dyson.cornell.edu.womeninleadership.SpeakerElement.onCreate(SpeakerElement.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5160)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4962)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:605)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:453)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:813)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2277)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:126)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:116)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1914)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at dyson.cornell.edu.womeninleadership.SpeakerElement.onCreate(SpeakerElement.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5160)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4962)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the layout for the activity where is crashes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/speakerElementName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/speakerElementPicture"
            android:src="@drawable/dash"
            android:layout_below="@id/speakerElementName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/bios" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/speakerElementPosition"
            android:text="Head of marketing and sales"
            android:layout_below="@id/speakerElementPicture"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/speakerElementBio"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed neque ut tortor ullamcorper laoreet. Suspendisse pellentesque sagittis felis, eget vestibulum ante lobortis lobortis. Duis mauris justo, elementum nec euismod quis, suscipit sed tortor. Vestibulum euismod vestibulum pellentesque"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/speakerElementPosition"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

From my Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SpeakerElement"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_speaker_element"
        android:parentActivityName=".speakers" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="dyson.cornell.edu.womeninleadership.speakers" />
    </activity>
```

Here is my SpeakerElement class:

```
package dyson.cornell.edu.womeninleadership;

import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SpeakerElement extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView name;
    TextView position;
    TextView bio;
    ImageView speakerImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speaker_element);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("speaker");

        // Saving each UI element to a local variable
        name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.speakerElementName);
        position = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.speakerElementPosition);
        bio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.speakerElementBio);
        speakerImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.speakerElementPicture);

        if (data.equals("SuzyWelch")) {
            name.setText("Suzy Welch");
            position.setText("Author and Public Speaker, Suzy Welch Communications");
            bio.setText("This is a test");
            speakerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dash);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.speaker_element, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at android.graphics.BitmapFactory`. How big is the picture you're trying to load?

Comment: WOW! 3,333 x 2,500. That was just a place holder. I switched that to a different picture and now its not crashing

Comment: Yeah, `bitmaps` can be tricky. Read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) for more tips.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the exception stack is a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError that is thrown when decoding one of your images in one of your ImageView's. In general, you should anticipate that your app gets no more than 16MB of RAM. Android's standard Bitmap uses 4 bytes per pixel. This means a single 4 Megapixel image will use all available RAM. Check your images, and downsize any images that are too big.

Another option, if your images don't require high color fidelity is to use a different [Bitmap.Config](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) that requires only 2 bytes per pixel. There may be a way to specify the Config via xml, but I am not aware of it. I would load the Bitmap in onCreate (using the lower fidelity Bitmap.Config value) and then call setImageBitmap on the ImageView.